# Unable to get two <p> or <div> in the footer to be stacked

Tags: html, css

[image]

I've tried having it be an unordered list item without it being a paragraph element, I've tried putting it in a div as well.  For some reason I'm just unable to get those to be stacked with the smaller "test" under the bigger TestTest.  Seems to work in the rest of the page if I have it as a separate div, just not sure of the reason why it's not working in the footer.

Here is my HTML and CSS:

```css
body {
  background-color: #414141;
  /* background: url(/images/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  resize: both;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden; */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: ubuntu-medium;
  src: url(/fonts/ubuntu-medium.ttf);
}

@media (max-width: 7680px) {
  body {
    background: url(/images/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    resize: both;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  body {
    background: url(/images/mobilebackground.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  }
}

#NavSection {
  margin-top: 3%;
}

#MainNav {
  position: left;
  margin-left: 11%;
}

#Menu li {
  font-family: ubuntu-medium;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #414141;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#Menu a:hover {
  text-decoration-color: #414141;
  text-underline-offset: 0.12em;
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  text-decoration-style: solid;
  text-decoration-thickness: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 13px 4px -3px rgba(65, 65, 65, 0.616);
}

hr {
  margin: 0px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: auto;
}

a {
  color: #414141;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
  color: #ff0000;
}

#SiteTitle {
  margin-left: 0.5%;
}

#TestTest {
  font-family: Impact;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #414141;
  text-decoration-thickness: 2px;
  text-underline-offset: 0.08em;
}

#Japan {
  color: red;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#SecondNav {
  float: right;
  font-family: ubuntu-medium;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #414141;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-right: 11%;
}

#SecondMenu a:hover {
  text-decoration: overline 4px solid #414141;
  box-shadow: 0px -13px 4px -3px rgba(65, 65, 65, 0.616);
}

#SecondMenu li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-family: ubuntu-medium;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #414141;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#ContentDiv {
  width: 70%;
  height: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 15%;
  transform: translateX(0%);
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

#ContentSection {
  width: 90%;
  height: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 5%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}

#Content {
  margin: 3%;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 7%;
  background-color: #414141;
  font-family: Impact;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#FooterTitle {
  float: right;
  margin: 0.5%;
}
#FooterJapan {
  color: #ff0000;
}
#FooterCaption {
  font-size: x-small;
  float: right;
  margin: 0.5%;
  font-family: ubuntu-medium;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    
    <div id="NavSection">
      <div id="TopNav">
        <nav id="MainNav">
          <ul id="Menu">
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>

      <hr />

      <div id="SecondNavSection">
        <nav id="SecondNav">
          <ul id="SecondMenu">
            <li><a href="">Archives</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Categories</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>

      <div id="SiteTitle">
        <h1 id="TestTest">Test<span id="Japan">Test</span></h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="ContentDiv">
      <main id="ContentSection">
        <div id="Content">
          <p>Content goes here.</p>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>

    <footer>
      <p id="FooterTitle">Test <span id="FooterJapan">Test</span></p>
      <p id="FooterCaption">Test</p>
    </footer>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using `float` for `FooterTitle` and `FooterCaption` -- So remove the `float:right;`

Then you can add `text-align:right;` to the `<footer>` CSS

```
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 7%;
  background-color: #414141;
  font-family: Impact;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align:right;
}

#FooterTitle {

  margin: 0.5%;
}
#FooterJapan {
  color: #ff0000;
}
#FooterCaption {
  font-size: x-small;

  margin: 0.5%;
  font-family: ubuntu-medium;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

The rest .. Like `height` and getting everything to show in the footer I trust you can do :) -- Personally, I think `height:7%;` is a bad idea .. Better to give it a static height height, or a height that statically will change inside media queries. --

[image: Screen Shot]

**OR**  You could scrap the text align right to get it to align left but still float right like:

```
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #414141;
  font-family: Impact;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;

}

#FooterTitle {

  margin: 0.5%;
}
#FooterJapan {
  color: #ff0000;
}
#FooterCaption {
  font-size: x-small;

  margin: 0.5%;
  font-family: ubuntu-medium;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#footer-right-content{
  float:right;
  text-align:left;
  width:100px;
}
```

HTML

```
<footer>
  <div id="footer-right-content">
    <p id="FooterTitle">Test <span id="FooterJapan">Test</span></p>
    <p id="FooterCaption">Test</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

[image: Second Way]